# R session aborted when trying to run plm

Tags: r, abort, lm, plm

Does anyone understand why my R session gets a fatal error: R session aborted when trying to run this panel linear model:

```
date1 <- c("01.01.2000","02.01.2000","03.01.2000","06.01.2000","07.01.2000","09.01.2000","01.01.2000","02.01.2000","03.01.2000","06.01.2000","07.01.2000","09.01.2000")
ret1 <- c(-2.0,1.1,3,1.4,-0.2, 0.6, 0.1, -0.21, -1.2, 0.9, 0.3, -0.1)
company1 <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2")
df <- data.frame(date1, ret1, company1, stringsAsFactors=F)

df$DATE <- df$date1
df$date1 <- NULL
df$RET <- df$ret1
df$ret1 <- NULL
df$PERMNO <- df$company1
df$company1 <- NULL


date2 <- c("02.01.2000","03.01.2000","06.01.2000","09.01.2000","03.01.2000","07.01.2000","09.01.2000")
news2 <- c("blabla11", "blabla12","blabla13","blabla14","blabla21","blabla22","blabla23")
company2 <- c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2")
klasse <- c("-1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0")

event <- data.frame(date2, news2, company2, klasse, stringsAsFactors=F)

event$DATE <- event$date2
event$date2 <- NULL
event$ARTICLE <- event$news2
event$news2 <- NULL
event$PERMNO <- event$company2
event$company2 <- NULL


mypanel <- merge(event, df, by.x=c("DATE", "PERMNO"), by.y=c("DATE", "PERMNO"))
mypanel

#         DATE PERMNO klasse  ARTICLE  RET
# 1 02.01.2000      1     -1 blabla11  1.1
# 2 03.01.2000      1      1 blabla12  3.0
# 3 03.01.2000      2      0 blabla21 -1.2
# 4 06.01.2000      1      0 blabla13  1.4
# 5 07.01.2000      2      1 blabla22  0.3
# 6 09.01.2000      1      1 blabla14  0.6
# 7 09.01.2000      2      0 blabla23 -0.1
```

when I try to run this:

```
mymodel <- plm(RET ~ klasse, data=mypanel,
             index=c("DATE", "PERMNO"),
             model="within", 
             effect="time")
```

I get a fatal error: R session aborted!

Does anyone else get this error when running this code?

Comment: I really love R studio but this error - which crashes the program - hits me every so often and it is not linked to any one command/function. It seems random but has been an issue for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and this is what I got:

Model Formula: RET ~ klasse

Coefficients: klasse0 klasse1 
0.11667 0.79167

Which version of R are you using? I'm using R 3.0.3.

Comment: R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: So the version might be the problem?

Comment: Downloaded version 3.0.3 again and it works! thank you!